# How to Install Ceiling Fan Control Wall Switch to Existing 2 Gang Wall Switch

Tags: wiring, switch, ceiling-fan, remote-control

In my bedroom, I have a ceiling fan (Casablanca Panama II, Model 6672R), no light, and operated with a remote control (Comfort Touch).

I would like to do away with the remote and control the fan with a existing switch on the wall. The switch is a dummy switch and is one of two. The other switch is for two recessed lights.

I have a fan switch I was hoping to be able to use. How do I wire the switch?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not type in all capital letters. It feels like SHOUTING.

Comment: There appear to be at least 3 white wires in the housing for the fan. That means that the unswitched (always hot) power from the wall goes to the fan _and_ to something else beyond the fan. If you put a switch on the wall for the fan, whatever else is connected to it will also be controlled by the switch. You may determine that this is OK, but that device might not like the "dimmed" power from the fan control.